# Как изменить (button) BackgroundImage на 10 секунд при нажатии на button?

Tags: swift

Пробовал через:

```
sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage (named: "название картинки в Assets"), for: UIControl.State)
```

Но выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'UIControl.State.Type' to expected argument type 'UIControl.State'

Comment: Изначально, я поставил себе задачу: При нажатии кнопки, она меняет свою картинку на другую на время проигрыша звука, который может быть разной длины.

Comment: Правильно будет например так: `sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage (named: "название картинки в Assets"), for: .normal)`, но в вашем вопросе совсем нет подробностей, которые вы указываете в комментариях, поэтому его могут закрыть. К тому же не представлена попытка вашего решения именно проблемы с изменением картинки по таймеру

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking